# remove custom taxonomy metabox form custom post type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type 'hotel' and custom 'taxonomy' so when administrator creates a new hotel and saves it it related custom taxonomy automatically get created but I don't want to show custom metabox in the admin side hotel edit page so for that I used WordPress function but nothing happen.

### My custom post code

```
  $Hotel_labels = array(
'name' => _x('Hotels', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Hotel', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Hotel'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add Hotel'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Hotel'),
'new_item' => __('New Hotel'),
'all_items' => __('All Hotels'),
'view_item' => __('View Hotel'),
'search_items' => __('Search Hotel'),
'not_found' =>  __('No Hotel found'),
'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Hotel found in Trash'), 
'parent_item_colon' => '',
'menu_name' => __('Hotel'),
);

register_post_type('Hotel',$Hotel_args);
```

### Custom taxonomy code

```
$Package_labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Package Hotels', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'hotel', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search hotels' ),
'popular_items' => __( 'Popular hotels' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All hotels' ),
'parent_item' => null,
'parent_item_colon' => null,
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit hotel' ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update hotel' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New hotel' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New hotel Name' ),
'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate hotels with commas' ),
'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove hotels' ),
'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used hotels' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Package Hotels' ),
);

 register_taxonomy('package_hotel','package',array(
'hierarchical' => false,
'labels' => $Package_labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
'query_var' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'hotels' ),
));
```

### code to remove custom taxonomy metabox form custom post type hotel page

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('tagsdiv_hotels', 'Hotel', 'side');
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your solution but I found my solution that I was not giving the metabox id attribute to `remove_meta_box('tagsdiv_hotels', 'Hotel', 'side');`
in right way .
so the right way is to append tagsdiv_in the beginning and after that add your metabox is like this `remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-package_hotel', 'hotel', 'side');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your taxonomy registration parameter `show_ui` to `false`...

```
 register_taxonomy('package_hotel','package',array(
'hierarchical' => false,
'labels' => $Package_labels,
'show_ui' => false,
'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
'query_var' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'hotels' ),
));
```

Comment: This will also hide the menu item for editing the taxonomy which may not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

change your metabox id "tagsdiv_hotels   "package_hotel"

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
        remove_meta_box('package_hotel', 'Hotel', 'side');
    }

    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Explain your answer. A code snippet is not an answer here.