# Taxonomy shows up twice on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I created a new **C**ustom **P**ost **T**ype called `Articles & Issues`. I then created a new taxonomy called `authors` on this CPT. I then went into `Advanced Custom Fields` and created a field group called `Article`. In it, I have `keywords` and `author`. I set the rules to show on Post Type -> is equal to -> Article (my Custom Post Type).

In the Field Group `Article` I then created Author (and Keywords), and under `Field Type` set it to Taxonomy -> Author.

The Issue I'm running into is that apparently Wordpress' native Authors taxonomy also shows up, see this image:

[image]

How do I display only the author ACF field, and hide the wordpress native author selection? I had to create this in the first place so that none of the Wordpress registered users are displayed as authors, and to prevent overlap with other modular CPTs on the site.
Thank you for any input.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215743/16

Comment: Simple and to the point, I thought that setting 'show_ui' => false would result in the ACF field not showing up anymore. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Custom Taxonomy Metabox from Custom Post Type Screen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102655/remove-custom-taxonomy-metabox-from-custom-post-type-screen)